# Create entity with no relations

Tags: rust, orm, sea-orm

Using SeaOrm, I want to create a model that has no relations. Essentially, a DB with one table.

This seems like it should be super easy, but the documentation doesn't cover this and the `DeriveEntityModel` macro requires all the boilerplate for entity relations to be present.

What I want is:

```
use sea_orm::entity::prelude::*;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, DeriveEntityModel)]
#[sea_orm(table_name = "device")]
pub struct Model {

    #[sea_orm(primary_key)]
    pub id: i32,

    #[sea_orm(column_name = "uuid")]
    pub uuid: Uuid,

    #[sea_orm(column_name = "location")]
    pub location: Option<String>,

    #[sea_orm(column_name = "lastHeard")]
    pub lastHeard: Option<DateTime>
}
```

And the error I get is:

```
cannot find type `Relation` in this scope

help: you might have meant to use the associated type: `Self::Relation`rustc(E0412)
the trait bound `models::device::ActiveModel: sea_orm::ActiveModelBehavior` is not satisfied

the trait `sea_orm::ActiveModelBehavior` is not implemented for `models::device::ActiveModel`
```

I'm thinking there must be another macro to use, one that doesn't require relations, but I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: Hello, Have you seen the following example? (https://github.com/SeaQL/sea-orm/tree/master/examples/rocket_example). It use only one table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks for trying SeaORM. Try to define an empty Relation enum like below.

```
use sea_orm::entity::prelude::*;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, DeriveEntityModel)]
#[sea_orm(table_name = "device")]
pub struct Model {

    #[sea_orm(primary_key)]
    pub id: i32,

    #[sea_orm(column_name = "uuid")]
    pub uuid: Uuid,

    #[sea_orm(column_name = "location")]
    pub location: Option<String>,

    #[sea_orm(column_name = "lastHeard")]
    pub lastHeard: Option<DateTime>
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, EnumIter, DeriveRelation)]
pub enum Relation {}

impl ActiveModelBehavior for ActiveModel {}
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that... It works, thanks!

Comment: Hahaaa lolll. If you got any other question please find us on [GitHub](https://github.com/SeaQL/sea-orm) or [Discord](https://discord.gg/RfBEXVeF)!

Comment: This is what the model generator created for me indeed.

Comment: That Discord link is expired.

Comment: Try this discord link https://discord.com/invite/uCPdDXzbdv

Comment: thanks a lot for this. made things super easy and faster. btw makes sense.